# Dropdown React No consigo que me ejecute una funcion cuando seleciono alguna de las opciones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente: Intento calcular los impuestos de un importe que el usuario introduce en un input.
Estoy utilizando React.js y componentes de React-bootstrap
Para ello he creado lo siguiente con componentes de React-bootstrap:

```js
 <InputGroup.Text id="basic-addon1" type="submit" >CALCULO SIN IVA</InputGroup.Text>
                    <FormControl
                        placeholder=""
                        aria-label=""
                        aria-describedby="basic-addon1"
                        onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <DropdownButton
                        variant="outline-secondary"
                        title="PPTO + IVA/IGIC"
                        id="input-group-dropdown-1"
                        onSelect={(e) => setId(e)}
                        onChange={handleChange}

                    >

                        <Dropdown.Item id="0" >Sin IVA </Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item id="1" >IVA al 21%</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item id="2" >IGIC al 7%</Dropdown.Item>

                    </DropdownButton>
 <FormControl aria-label="Number input with dropdown button"></FormControl>
```

```js
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(" ");
    const [getTotal, setTotal] = useState([]);
    const [getTotal2, setTotal2] = useState([]);
    const [id, setId] = useState([]);

    console.log(quantity);
    console.log(id);

    const handleChange = () => {

        for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

            if (id === "0") {
                alert("Presupuesto sin impuestos");
                console.log("Presupuesto sin impuestos");
                return quantity;

            } else if (id === "1") {
                let newQuantityIva = quantity * 0.21;
                console.log(newQuantityIva);
                let newTotal = parseFloat(quantity) + parseFloat(newQuantityIva) + "€";
                console.log(newTotal);
                setTotal([...getTotal, newTotal]);

                return newTotal;

            } else if (id === "2") {
                let newQuantityIgic = quantity * 0.07;
                console.log(newQuantityIgic);
                let newTotal2 = parseFloat(quantity) + parseFloat(newQuantityIgic) + "€";
                console.log(newTotal2);
                setTotal2([...getTotal2, newTotal2]);
                return newTotal2;

            }
        }
    }
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el FormControl el usuario pone la cantidad y utilizo el setQuantity para tener en quantity la cantidad (esto funciona porque el console.log funciona). La segunda parte sería que cuando se seleccione cualquier Dropdown.Item el setId obtenga y guarde el id (esto tb funciona por que lo veo con el console.log).
El problema está que no consigo que funciones el handleChange() y que me lo pinte en el FormControl de abajo.

Cualquier ayuda o idea será bienvenida gracias.